# Hover preview coded in CSS: caption box doesn't resize according to image size

Tags: html, css, image

Sorry if title or this comment isn't that much understandable, I don't speak English.

The problem is that, I wrote a code that when user hove his mouse on picture, the picture will be previewed in a bigger size. When enlarged, the pic will include a description, the problem is when the picture is very big, the description box will not stretch accordingly. I found this problem when I wanted to make large images preview to be previewed smaller, and to solve this problem I wrote this line:

```
ul.enlarge span img {
max-width:600%;
```

}

It solved the resize problem but now the caption doesn't fit the new size.

I found on internet tutorials, this one is neat and similar for what I want but I still face the same problem.

Note: If image is small, the caption will not face any problem, the problem is only for big images.

Thank you.

```css
ul.enlarge{
list-style-type:none;
}
ul.enlarge li{
display:inline-block;
position: relative; 
z-index: 0;
margin:5px 5px 0 0px;

}
ul.enlarge span{
position:absolute; 
left: -9999px; 
} 

ul.enlarge img{
background-color:#eaeaed; 
padding: 4px; 
border: 1px solid #9799a7;

}
ul.enlarge li:hover{
z-index: 50;  

}
ul.enlarge li:hover span{ 
top: -20px; 
left: 50px; 
}

ul.enlarge li:hover:nth-child(2) span{
left: -100px; 
}
ul.enlarge li:hover:nth-child(3) span{
left: -200px; 
}
ul.enlarge span{

    padding: 10px; 
    background:#eaeaed;
 text-align:center;
    color: #495a62;
}

/* This is to solve the problem when huge images are previewed, it shows them smaller */
ul.enlarge span img {
 max-width:600%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="enlarge">
<li> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" alt="description" width="100px" height="100px"/>
<span> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" alt="description"/>
<div class="phototitle">
Photo caption is too small or don't fit image's size. 
</div>  
</span>
</li>
</ul>
  </body>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, the caption behaves exactly as it's supposed to, taking the whole width of the element, so I assume you're looking for something else. Could you please upload an image of the desired behavior?

Comment: sorry, here is an image that shows how I want it to be, the description box does not contain the image nor the description is under the image. Its as if its a separate box:. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sb5b.png

Comment: have you seen my answer @Lan ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not setting a width to `ul.enlarge li:hover span`.
 For example:

```
ul.enlarge li:hover span {
    top: -20px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px; /* You need to set a width here */
}
```

**Here's a [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/tq44xxvp/1/)**

> Although if I were you, I would make some changes in this code.
>   First of all I would remove `position: relative;` from `ul.enlarge li` because it's avoiding your `span` of having a bigger size, because it's depending on the `ul.enlarge li` size/width because of the `position: relative;` you added :

```
ul.enlarge li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;  /* I'd remove this line */
    z-index: 0;  /* And I'd remove this line as well because it's doing nothing here */
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0px;
}
```

I'd also **remove** this completely

```
ul.enlarge li:hover{
    z-index: 50;  
}
```

and I also would rearrange some parts of the code like this as well:

```
.enlarge span img {
    height: 90%;
}
.enlarge .phototitle {
    height: 10%;
}
.enlarge li:hover span {
    top: 8%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
.enlarge span{
    position:absolute; 
    display:none;
} 
.enlarge li:hover > span {
    display: block;
}
```

> **Note:** It looks like that this code you had does the job of hiding the content and show it when hovering the image, although it's not the
>   right way of doing it. This is a better way.

I've exchanged this:

```
ul.enlarge span{
    position:absolute; 
    left: -9999px; 
}
```

For this:

```
.enlarge span{
    position:absolute; 
    display:none;
} 
.enlarge li:hover > span {
    display: block;
}
```

**Here's the [whole code](http://jsfiddle.net/tq44xxvp/4/) and how it looks like**